# How to format background color using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with the styles on the website here: http://www.grabapper.com

I am trying to include background-color `#2ba6cb` on the hero unit.  When I include:

```
<div class="row" style ='background-color: #2ba6cb;'>
```

The color doesn't go all the way to the edge of the page.  How do I get the background color to go to the edge of the page?

Comment: You need to reformat the HTML.  That container is not wide enough.  You will need to make a container that reaches 100% width

Comment: You want to change the whole background color of the page? Just use `body {background-color:#2ba6cb;}`

Comment: No not the entire page.  Just the first module.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move your row before `<div class="container marketing">` and wrap it with a new container, because current container width is 1170px (not 100%):

```
<div class='hero'>
  <div class="row">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
  background-color: #2ba6cb;
  padding: 0 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 40):

Bootstrap default "[contextual backgrounds](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds)" helper classes to change the background color:

```
.bg-primary
.bg-default
.bg-info
.bg-warning
.bg-danger
```

If you need set custom background color then, you can write your own custom classes in style.css( a custom css file) 
    example below

```
.bg-pink
{
  background-color: #CE6F9E;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add a div around the `container` so it looks like:

```
<div style="background: red;">
  <div class="container marketing">
    <h2 style="padding-top: 60px;"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```